# "G is undefined" when using javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a javascript object to populate a dropdown based on a previous input.

My object looks like the following:

```
var cars = {
        'A.C.' : ["16","16/80","16/90","2 Litre","2-1","3 Litre","428","Ace","Aceba","Cobra","Greyhound","Me","Shelby"],

        'Alfa Romeo' : ["145","146"]
}
```

Its bigger than that but you get the jist. Everything was working fine until I tried to use the data to populate a dropdown based on the manufacturer. My jQuery code to populate the dropdown looks like this:

```
function populateModelDropdown(manufacturer) {

    //clear the old dropdown values
    $('#carModel').html("");

    //getthe previous selection if one exists
    var prevSelection = $("#carModel_hidden").val();

    $.each(cars[manufacturer], function(val, text) {

        if (text == prevSelection) {
            $('#carModel').append(
                $('<option selected></option>').val(text).html(text));
        }
        else {
            $('#carModel').append(
                $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text));
        }
    });


}
```

However, as soon as I enter the each loop, I get the error "G is undefined" coming from the file "jquery-tools.js" which is a jquery library which I do not touch.

I see that this problem has occured before but with JSON data. Can anyone point out as to why its occuring for me?

Thanks.

Comment: just a note, your option builder should quote the selected attribute like this: `$('<option selected="selected"></option>')`

Comment: Why not take out the reference to that file if you don't even use it?

Comment: @ryanulit: the file is used but I do not "touch" the file as in I have made no changes to it.

@scunliffe: thanks :)

Comment: Does your data contain things like "O'G"... that is actually returned as `'O'G'`? If so, the first string would be `"O"` followed by a variable called `G` (which would be undefined).  E.g. if you change the returned data to a basic hard coded list of three test values, does it work?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a lot of internal error/consistency checking. An error like this just means that you've handed jQuery something that it can't digest; in this case I suspect that there's something problematic with the "cars" definition. The "g" in the error is a name that's been changed by the squisher; if you run with the un-squished version of jQuery you can usually make more sense of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop did the job!

```
function populateModelDropdown(manufacturer) {

    if (manufacturer.length > 0) {

        $('#carModel').html("");

        var prevSelection = $("#carModel_hidden").val();

        for (var i=0; i < cars[manufacturer].length; i++) {

            var model = cars[manufacturer][i];

            if (model == prevSelection) {
                $('#carModel').append(
                    $('<option selected="selected"></option>').val(model).html(model));
            }
            else {
                $('#carModel').append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(model).html(model));
            }
        }

    }

}
```